# The game freezes sometimes when I Exit To Desktop. How to regain control?

Tags: civilization-6

The game freezes when I exit to desktop sometime. How do I close the game without hard-turning off my computer or restarting it.

I cannot see my desktop, start menu or taskbar.

Sometimes ALT-TAB cannot take me out.

Comment: In my experience, Civ6 can be very slow to start and stop. Try leaving it alone for a few minutes to see if it manages to finish by itself.

Comment: @HongOoi I've had this happen to mean and it was still stuck after an hour. It seems to be a legitimate hang in the game. The only way out was to terminate the process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The game crashes when exiting to desktop while in a game. Here  are a couple of methods.

Method 1: Exit to the main menu instead of quitting to desktop from a running game.

Method 2: If Stuck!

Here is a method to force the civilization game to close by ending its process.

```
(Bring up task manager)    
Press CONTROL-SHIFT-ESC 
OR
CONTROL-ALT-DEL and then select it from the list.

You may need to click "More Details" at the bottom if that is showing as an option.
Goto details tab
Find process CivilizationVI.exe
Right click, End Process
```

Perhaps to be done now as it will help later as I have had the task manager appear under the game (dumb).

```
Bring up the task manager.
```

`Under options menu, enable ALWAYS ON TOP`

Once you have done this once or twice or know how to use the task manager, it will become second nature.

Comment: Omg you can PUT IT ALWAYS ON TOP!? I must have rebooted my PC hundreds of time because the screen was frozen on a game / black screen yet the PC was still responsive, but I just couldn't get to my Task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

If you have windows 10, and the game screen is preventing you from seeing other apps, then make a second desktop and from the second desktop run task manager and end the game task.